# grails validation of immutable fields

Tags: validation, grails, immutability

I have 4 fields that takes a price (BigDecimal) but only one of them should contain a price. If price2 contains 255.95 and someone want's to enter a price in price1 Then this should be rejected with a message which says that you have to clean the other (price2 in this case)
I tried to do that in the domain but it didn't work for me.

An example:

```
class Author {
    def String name
    def String email
    def BigDecimal price1
    def BigDecimal price2
    def BigDecimal price3
//    static hasMany = [books: Book]

    static constraints = {
        name nullable:true
        email nullable:true
        price1(nullable:true,
           validator: { val, obj -> 
              (obj.price2==null) and (obj.price3 == null) }) 
        price2(nullable:true, 
           validator: { val, obj -> 
              (obj.price1==null) and (obj.price3 == null) }) 
        price3(nullable:true, 
           validator: { val, obj -> 
              (obj.price1==null) and (obj.price2 == null) })   
    }
    static mapping = {
        name    column: "AuthorName", sqltype:"char", length:25
    }
    String toString() {
        return name
    }
    def beforeValidate() {
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: masterdetail.Author.and() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]
Possible solutions: any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), find(java.lang.String), find(masterdetail.Author)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at masterdetail.Author$__clinit__closure1$_closure3.doCall(Author.groovy:16)
```

So, what to do?

Comment: Boolean conditionals are anded with `&&`.

Comment: Of course, I usually programming with DELPHI, so sometimes I don't recognize my obvious misstakes. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the example to show the working version in case it would interest someone.

Comment: If you have solved the question you should answer yourself, and mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Yeah @larand, what ---^ said, edit the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem with some help fro doelleri.
I edited the question so it contains the final solution.